# Extension method to filter a list of concrete types based on interface?

Tags: c#-3.0, extension-methods

I have a multiple classes that implement an interface. I want to create an extension method to filter a list of these classes based on a value.  Here's a hypothetical example:

```
public enum Transmission
{ 
    Standard = 1,
    Automatic = 2
}

public interface ICar
{
    Transmission Tranny { get; set; }
}

public class Car : ICar
{
    public Transmission Tranny { get; set; }
    public string Make { get;set;}
}

public static class CarExtensions
{
    public static List<ICar> OnlyAuto(this List<ICar> cars)
    {
        return cars.Where(x => x.Tranny == Transmission.Automatic).ToList();
    }
}
```

I want to create an extension method to filter a list of cars...but this one doesn't kick in for

```
var x = new List<Car>();
x.OnlyAuto <-- compile error...
```

the extension method doesn't intellisense?

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't specific to extension methods. Given the definitions from your example the following results in a compiler-error:

```
void DoStuff(List<ICar> cars)
{
}

DoStuff(new List<Car>());
```

The problem is that even though the elements of the `List<Car>` implement `ICar` the type `List<Car>` cannot be used in places where a `List<ICar>` is expected.

In the example you could use

```
var x = new List<ICar>(); 
x.OnlyAuto();
```

or add the following extension-method:

```
public static IEnumerable<ICar> OnlyAuto(this IEnumerable<ICar> cars)
{
   return cars.Where(x => x.Tranny == Transmission.Automatic).ToList();
}
```

and use Cast:

```
var x = new List<Car>();
(x.Cast<ICar>()).OnlyAuto();
```

If you search google for "C# covariance" you will find that a lot of people has written about this problem. And it seems that in c# 4.0 IEnumerable is covariant, meaning that you can eliminate the use of `Cast` in the example above.